# Gurobi does not recognize LP file

Tags: c#, linear-programming, gurobi

When trying to open a Linear Programming problem from text with Gurobi+C# it throws the error: 10012 Unable to open file "Maximize" for input.
Maximise is the first word of the text and when using

```
foreach (string s in args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

i get the correct output from the text file. Please help!

```
using System;
using Gurobi;

class lp_cs
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    args = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Ben\Documents\Visual     Studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication5\ConsoleApplication5\mps.lp");
    foreach (string s in args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
    if (args.Length < 1)
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Please Wait..");
        return;
    }

    try
    {
        GRBEnv env = new GRBEnv();
        GRBModel model = new GRBModel(env, args[0]);

        model.Optimize();

        int optimstatus = model.Get(GRB.IntAttr.Status);

        if (optimstatus == GRB.Status.INF_OR_UNBD)
        {
            model.GetEnv().Set(GRB.IntParam.Presolve, 0);
            model.Optimize();
            optimstatus = model.Get(GRB.IntAttr.Status);
        }

        if (optimstatus == GRB.Status.OPTIMAL)
        {
            double objval = model.Get(GRB.DoubleAttr.ObjVal);
            Console.WriteLine("Optimal objective: " + objval);
        }
        else if (optimstatus == GRB.Status.INFEASIBLE)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Model is infeasible");

            model.ComputeIIS();
            model.Write("model.ilp");
        }
        else if (optimstatus == GRB.Status.UNBOUNDED)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Model is unbounded");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Optimization was stopped with status = "
                               + optimstatus);
        }

        model.Dispose();
        env.Dispose();

    }
    catch (GRBException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hibakód: " + e.ErrorCode + ". " + e.Message);
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

With

```
args = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Ben\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication5\ConsoleApplication5\mps.lp");
```

you are overwriting the `args` parameter of your `main()` method with an array of all lines of the input file. That's why in

```
GRBModel model = new GRBModel(env, args[0]);
```

`args[0]` contains a string with the first line of your LP file instead of the filename.